# Execute shell script using Python?

Tags: python, bash, shell, subprocess

I have a shell script in my JSON document `jsonStr`.. I am trying to execute that shell script using Python subprocess module after deserializing the jsonStr -

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import subprocess
import json

jsonStr = '{"script":"#!/bin/bash \\n STRING="Hello World" \\n echo $STRING \\n"}'
j = json.loads(jsonStr)

print "start"
subprocess.call(j['script'], shell=True)
print "end"
```

But somehow whenever I run my above python script, I always get an error like this -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "shellscript", line 27, in <module>
    j = json.loads(jsonStr)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 326, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Expecting , delimiter: line 1 column 34 (char 34)
```

Any thoughts what wrong I am doing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the JSON parser is being confused by a " inside a ", particularly where it says hello world.

Observe that all the JSON escaping rules can be elegantly obtained by just asking the python JSON library for the correct string.

```
import json
jsoncnt = {'script':'#!/bin/bash \n STRING="Hello World" \n echo $STRING \n'}
jsonStr = json.dumps(jsoncnt)
print jsonStr
q = json.loads(jsonStr)
```

Answer (score 2):

It is woking fine for me..

```
import subprocess
import json

json_dict = {"script":'#!/bin/bash \\n STRING="Hello World" \\n echo $STRING \\n'}

dump = json.dumps(json_dict)

j = json.loads(dump)

print j
print j['script']

print "start"
subprocess.call(j['script'], shell=True)
print "end"
```

can you please paste code How u r using json.dumps()

Result:

```
{u'script': u'#!/bin/bash \\n STRING="Hello World" \\n echo $STRING \\n'}
#!/bin/bash \n STRING="Hello World" \n echo $STRING \n
start
end
```

Comment: No it isn't. Observe that in the OP's code your json_dict is a string not a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Wrong JSON format.It should be:

```
jsonStr = '{"script":"#!/bin/bash \\n STRING=\\"Hello World\\" \\n echo $STRING \\n"}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Double quote character (") is not allowed inside JSON. You should substitute it with escaped single quote like this:

```
jsonStr = '{"script":"#!/bin/bash \\n STRING=\'Hello World\' \\n echo $STRING \\n"}'
```